# How can I make link on web page in window using pyqt4?

Tags: python, qt, hyperlink, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a problem. 
Can I make a link on the web page in the window and when the user clicks on it, the web page will be open in the browser. 
For example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = QtGui.QWidget()
main.setGeometry(200, 200, 200, 100)
label = QtGui.QLabel('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow/</a>')
box = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
box.addWidget(label)
main.setLayout(box)

main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is it really?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is of course good that you found answer, but there is special class, which allows you to open URL in default browser or files in default editors/players etc. It is `QDesktopServices`. For example:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDesktopServices
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def link(self, linkStr):

        QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl(linkStr))

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.label.linkActivated.connect(self.link)
        self.label.setText('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stackoverflow/</a>')
```

This example is definitely larger, but you should know about `QDesktopServices`, because it is very useful class.

Comment: OK! Thak you! I will read more clearly about QDesktopServices, of course.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry. I have already searched the answer.

```
label.setText('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Link</a>')
label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
```

Comment: In order for this to work properly, the string should not include characters like "\n" before HTML tags, or else, it would be parsed as plain text. Also, flags like Qt.TextInteractionFlag.TextSelectableByMouse should be avoided to be able to click the link.